# What If Coroutine Doesn't Run to the End?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, coroutine, fsm

I have some states for my player that I control two of them with a bool called isReloading. If it is true, then the player reloads while idling or running, and whether inside of base or not. If it is not true, then just runs or idles.

I use a coroutine to give enough time to the player  to switch between reload animations, and I control the "isReloading" bool here.

```
IEnumerator Reload()
{
    if(isReloading)
        yield break;
    
    isReloading = true;
    Debug.Log("Reloading...");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.3f); 
    currentBulletCount = maxBulletCount;
    isReloading = false;
}
```

So that my problem is; if I switch to another animation such as insideBaseRun before the Reload method finishes, which means 3.3 seconds are never up, isReloading bool cannot be false. This is what I guess, and it's a huge problem because I need the bool to be false to switch other animations from any of the reload related animations.
Here is where I wrote the player states' conditions in another script using in FixedUpdate.

```
if (joystick.Horizontal != 0 || joystick.Vertical != 0)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rigidBody.velocity);

        if (OutSide)    // controls if the player inside of the base or not.
        {
            if(BaseBulletSpawner.isReloading)
                executingState = ExecutingState.RUNRELOAD;
            else if(!BaseBulletSpawner.isReloading)
                executingState = ExecutingState.OUTRUN;
        }
        else    executingState = ExecutingState.INRUN;

    }
    else
    {
        if (OutSide)    
        {
            if(BaseBulletSpawner.isReloading)
                executingState = ExecutingState.IDLERELOAD;
            else if(!BaseBulletSpawner.isReloading)
                executingState = ExecutingState.OUTIDLE;
        }
        else    executingState = ExecutingState.INIDLE;
    }
```

Once the method is interrupted, the player simply cycles through the reload animations because the bool is always true. how do i fix this?

by the way this is the whole code about the coroutine stuff.

```
public void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (timer >= speedTime)
    {
        if (currentBulletCount > 0)
        {
            isReloading = false;
            currentBulletCount --;
            GetBullet();
        }
        else if(currentBulletCount == 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Reload());
        }

        timer = 0;
    }

    timer += 0.02f;
}

IEnumerator Reload()
{
    if(isReloading)
        yield break;
    
    isReloading = true;
    Debug.Log("Reloading...");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.3f);
    currentBulletCount = maxBulletCount;
    isReloading = false;
}
```

Comment: Are you cancelling the coroutine?

Comment: @hijinxbassist I guess the answer is yes. 3.3 seconds is total duration of the reload animation. If I switch to running animation in base(INRUN -It doesn't need the bool-) before this time is up, the coroutine is interrupted or, as you say,  cancelled. While this happening, "isReloading" is setting to true.